# Right join using JPA criteria api

Tags: java, jpa, criteria

I'm trying to implement this sql query using jpa criteria api :

```
SELECT F.* FROM PF right join F on F.FID = PF.FID WHERE PF.PFID is null;
```

Which also can be written as:

```
SELECT F.* FROM F left join PF on F.FID = PF.FID WHERE PF.FID is null;
```

This is what I tried:

```
public List<F> listFWithoutP() {
    final CriteriaBuilder builder = getCriteriaBuilder();
    final CriteriaQuery<F> query = builder.createQuery(F.class);
    final Root<PF> from = query.from(PF.class);

    Join<PF, F> join = from.join(PF_.f, JoinType.RIGHT);

    query.select(join.get(PF_.f))
            .where(builder.isNull(from.get(PF_.pFId)));

    final TypedQuery<F> typedQuery = getEntityManager().createQuery(query);
    return typedQuery.getResultList();
}
```

But it doesn't work, I get the following error in this line : `query.select(join.get(PF_.f))`

```
The method get(SingularAttribute<? super F,Y>) in the type Path<F> is not applicable for the arguments (SingularAttribute<PF,F>)
```

How can I solve this ?

## Update:

These are my entities :

```
    public class F extends AbstractDomain<Long> {

        @Id
        @Column
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "idgen")
        private Long fId;

        @Column(nullable = false)
        private String lib;
    }

public class PF extends AbstractDomain<Long> {

    @Id
    @Column
    private Long pFId;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(nullable = false)
    private P p;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(nullable = false)
    private F f;
}
```

## Update 2:

It seems like RIGHT JOIN is not supported by the jpa criteria api, so this can be done using the second query.

Comment: TRY
`TypedQuery<F> queryTaskEntity =getEntityManager().createQuery("FROM F left join PF on F.FID = PF.FID WHERE PF.FID is null",F.class);`

Comment: @KlevinDelimeta thanks but I want this to be done using the criteria api

Comment: Please describe what "it doesn't work" actually means. Do you get an Exception or a ResultList with values different than what you expect?

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS please check my edit

Comment: Not 100% sure, but i don't think `join.get(PF_.f)` makes sense, as join already refers to a join made on the PF_.f attribute. I think it should just be `select(join)` if you want to select the F objects through the join you did from PF.

Comment: care to share your entity "PF" ? because without it, how does anyone know what field "f" represents?!

Comment: @DN1 Well, assuming that this line is right: `Join<PF, F> join = from.join(PF_.f, JoinType.RIGHT);` we can make an educated guess that PF_.f is the foreign key/link from the PF entity to the F entity.

Comment: @DN1 please check my update

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS When I tried `select(join)` I got this exception : `java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: RIGHT JOIN not supported`

Answer (score 0):

```
 final Session session = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);
        final Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(PF.class, "pf")
                .createAlias("pf.f", "f")
 .add(Restrictions.eqProperty("pf.pFId",
                        "f.fId"))
.add(Restrictions.isNull("pf.pFId"));

Hello Aimad,
please try this criteria query and let me know if that works,this criteria would exactly replicate your SQL query.
```

Comment: This looks like Hibernate Criteria API. But the question asked for JPA Criteria API solution.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't do that, since I'm using JPA, as @OHGODSPIDERS mentioned.